# mktemp command in Chef

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

does anyone know if Chef has a resource that is similar `mktemp` command on linux?

Basically, I'm looking for a way to download a file remotely and save it under /tmp but I want it save to a uniq file name

```
remote_file "/tmp/ec2-ami-tools.zip" do
  source "http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads/ec2-ami-tools-1.5.6.zip"
  action :create
end
```

instead of using `/tmp/ec2-ami-tools.zip` as the destination file name, I want to have a safe uniq file name. Beside using datetime random, is there an official resource doing that in Chef? I'm wondering if Chef has resource that can generate UUID

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain a little more your use case ? I hardly see how to get idempotent with `mktemp`, but ruby has an equivalent IIRC. With a little more detail on what you try to achieve we may give better advice.

Comment: I would like to download a zip file from internet, store it locally in temp folder with a uniq name (ex: /tmp/abc123234141234.zip) and then I run unzip command to unzip it (ex: unzip /tmp/abc123234141234.zip).

Comment: What I don't understand is the wish to use a unique name not being the downloaded file name or a choose name. Have a look at the Ark cookbook which take cares of download and unpack, it should answer your need I think. (sorry no link at this time)

Answer (score 1):

To exactly answer your question (creating a tempfile):

```
require 'tempfile'

mydest = Tempfile.new('ec2-ami-tools.zip')

remote_file mydest do 
  source "http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads/ec2-ami-tools-1.5.6.zip"
  action :create
  notifies :run,"execute[unzip #{mydest}", :immediately
end
execute "unzip #{mydest}" do
  action :nothing
end
```

I **highly** discourage doing that as at each run the file would be downloaded and unzipped (the Tempfile will change) without any idempotency of the recipe.

---

The [ark cookbook](https://github.com/burtlo/ark) can help you on this case.

It has a LighWeight Resource Provider aimed exactly at this goal, downloading a tarball, extracting it and optionnaly doing something after that.

Exemple from the ark README:

> This example copies ivy.tar.gz to /var/cache/chef/ivy-2.2.0.tar.gz,
>   unpacks its contents to /usr/local/ivy-2.2.0/ -- stripping the leading
>   directory, and symlinks /usr/local/ivy to /usr/local/ivy-2.2.0
>
> ```
>  # install Apache Ivy dependency resolution tool
>  ark "ivy" do
>    url 'http://someurl.example.com/ivy.tar.gz'
>    version '2.2.0'
>    checksum '89ba5fde0c596db388c3bbd265b63007a9cc3df3a8e6d79a46780c1a39408cb5'
>    action :install
>  end
> ```

Adapted to your exemple I would do something like this:

```
ark 'ec2-ami-tools' do
  url 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads/ec2-ami-tools-1.5.6.zip'
  version '1.5.6'
  action :install
end
```

The checksum will avoid a call to the webserver to see if the file has changed as the on disk zip checksum will be compared with the resource checksum and if they match it will stop at this point.

The ckecksum is a `sha256sum` of the file.